# 'ptr = nil' vs '[ptr release]' in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, memory, pointers

I'm new to Objective-C and having to allocate and deallocate memory. I find that sometimes when I try to use `[ptr release]` before reassigning a pointer, I end up with a `SIGABRT` later on, whereas if I use `ptr = nil` I don't, but I'm not sure if that actually deallocates what that pointer was pointing to. So I'd like to know exactly what `ptr = nil` does, as opposed to `[ptr release]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be a problem with a lack of understanding of Cocoa's memory management rules, specifically to do with object ownership.  Depending on how you create an object, either you own it or something else does.  Whether you need to release an object depends on whether you own the object (you've either retained it, or you've created it using a method beginning with `alloc`, `new`, `copy`, or `mutableCopy`).  You can read more about the rules in detail in [Apple's documentation on memory management](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html).

In addition, you should pay attention to any rules on properties.  As sergio mentioned, if a property specifies that it's retaining an object, it will handle calls to `retain` and `release` on assignment.  So, for example, if you allocate something using `alloc`, you own that object.  If you then assign it to a property that retains the object, you *and* the property are retaining the object, so depending on what you're doing afterward, you may also want to release the object to relinquish ownership of the object.

Setting a simple pointer to `nil` won't deallocate the object, nor will it count as a `release`.  So, depending on how you create the object, you should know whether you need to release the object or not.  The documentation linked above includes examples that should help you get up to speed on this as well.  One caveat: this stuff sort of changes with automatic reference counting, since you don't do *any* handling of `retain`, `release`, etc. and the compiler takes over for the most part, but if you're not using ARC, don't worry about that just yet (but do worry about it later).

Comment: So say I have a class property that I retain:
@property (nonatomic, retain) ResultsVC* resultsVC;

And then I allocate it:
self.resultsVC = [[ResultsVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"ResultsVC" bundle:nil];

Do I now need to release it twice to avoid leaks?

Comment: No, you need to release it once after assigning it to the property.  Later in your `dealloc` method (or some other place if you're freeing up memory) you need to set the property to `nil` to release it again.  Again, the _property_ retained it, and the property will release it when its value changes (either to `nil` or another object).

Answer (score 2):

`ptr = nil` will make your `ptr` variable has a nil value and will not release your pointer; so the reason why it is working without SIGABRT is the object does not get dealloc'ed.

Assigning `nil` will also imply a `release` when you are assigning to a `retain` property:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) .... ptr;
.....
self.ptr = nil;
```

It is good practice to follow a `release` statement with an assignment to nil:

```
[ptr release];
ptr = nil;
```

this will prevent any unwanted use of the deallocated object after release (this mostly is meaningful with class ivars that could be used in a different method).

If you could provide some code showing the SIGABRT, it would be easier to be spot on.

Answer (score 2):

Using :

```
[ptr release];
```

you are actually decrementing the `retainCount` of `ptr`. If the `retainCount` for `ptr` drops down to 0, `ptr` will be deallocated and the memory too.

When you write `ptr = nil;`, you are just 'reseting' the memory address `ptr` is pointing to.

Comment: And writing `ptr = nil;` instead of or before `[ptr release];` will cause a leak.

Comment: "If the retainCount for ptr drops down to 0, ptr will be deallocated and the memory too." --If I want to reuse the pointer to point to something else, but don't need the object it was pointing to anymore, is there a way to deallocate the object and not the pointer?

Comment: Just send your object a `release` message and then reassign the pointer variable anything you want !